# Change Picklist for Standard Object in Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, picklist, package

I have a requirement whereby I need to add a new entry to the "Type" Picklist in the "Campaigns" standard Object. I need to add a new entry in the picklist in addition to the ones already provided by Salesforce.

I was able to do this using the Point and Click mechanism by going to Setup->Customize->Objects->Campaigns->Fields. However could you guys please let me know as to how I can add this change in my managed package.

What I want is that when somebody installs my App, then he/she should see this value in their Campaign Types.

Your help will be of great use.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's possible to add custom picklist values to a standard field in a managed package though. (I believe I read this somewhere but I can be wrong)

Also make sure to check out the following similar question on how to manage changing picklist values in managed packages:
[What are the best practices for managing changing picklist values in managed packages?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/what-are-the-best-practices-for-managing-changing-picklist-values-in-managed-pac)