# Override tab settings in push upgrade

Tags: tab, push-upgrade, page-layout

The question is simple: why doesn't my client's organisation get his tabs hidden/shown depending on the settings I've placed in the developer org layouts? I import the profiles and layouts but the tab settings is never changed.

The same happens when overriding a page layout of an object which already existed in a version before and has a new layout.

Comment: **RELATED:** [What are the best practices for managing changing picklist values in managed packages?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/what-are-the-best-practices-for-managing-changing-picklist-values-in-managed-pac)

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce have made some design choices when managed packages are upgraded (which AFAIK is what a push upgrade does). Essentially they feel that overwriting local changes is a worse thing to do than to fail to update things like layouts and picklist content and help on fields (and I assume from your question but haven't experienced tab visibility). I'm afraid I can't find the thread where a Salesforce product manager expressed this view but its somewhere out there.

I would argue that the option should be made available to overwrite (or not) and there is at least one idea posted suggesting "overwrite if not locally changed". The lack of this feature results in lots of costly and risky manual work. But I don't think there is any momentum behind changing this.

Comment: Does this apply only to managed packages are upgrades, or all page layout pushes? If it's directly related to managed packages being pushes out via Salesforce, is there some way to push these updates out that might be automatize? Also, new to SF, but swear that internally in SF's setup options to force overrides of user-configs such as tabs; realize this is different, but clearly related I would think.

Comment: @blunders This applies to updates done via new managed package versions. You can certainly use the Ant tooling or Force IDE or a tool you write yourself (and I presume change sets but I don't have much experience of those) to overwrite.