# Extension package cannot add picklist values to a base package's field. Really?

Tags: managed-package, picklist, isv, managed-extension

My managed package `EXTENSION` is extending the package `BASE`. `BASE` contains object `CustomObject__c` with picklist field `pkl_Status__c`.

In `EXTENSION` I add some new RecordTypes for `CustomObject__c` and some picklist values for `pkl_Status__c` per RecordType.

All of that seems to get packaged and uploaded but...in after installation none of the added picklist values can be found in the target org.

Did I miss to package something or this this not possible at all?

Comment: My guess is that it is the same narrow thinking that applies when managed package upgrades are done, where local modifications to picklists are assumed and so automated changes are never done  - [What are the best practices for managing changing picklist values in managed packages?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/what-are-the-best-practices-for-managing-changing-picklist-values-in-managed-pac).

Answer (score 1):

I guess this section of the documentation ["Special Behavior of Components in Packages"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_behavior.htm) explains why:

> During a package upgrade, no new picklist values are installed into the subscriber’s organization for existing fields. Any picklist values deleted by the developer are still available in the subscriber’s organization.

I was just upgrading an org which had my managed package already installed, so the new Picklist values were not added.

Comment: Exactly right. Once you install a package updates or extensions will never change the values because they're subscriber mutable. There's no obviously correct way to merge these changes, so salesforce doesn't try.